# Duplicate Entries in Backend of Playa Field 4.4.5

Tags: playa

I'm currently working with Playa on a project and having an issue where playa is creating what looks like duplicate items in its list, when editing a entry based on any number of categories being selected for that entry.

I have attached a video for easy reference of the bug I am encountering. I have used playa on many other projects and have not run into this issue before.

[Video Example of Issue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-5N2tW-C7o)